# Python Tuple Problems

Tags: python, tuples

I'm new to python and as far as i can tell i'm recieving this Tuple Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 5, in main
    respons3 = api.get_summoner_by_name('hi im gosan')
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 31, in get_summoner_by_name
    return self._request(api_url)
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 12, in _request
    for key, value in params.items():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

in

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=()):
        args = {'api_key': self.api_key}
        for key, value in params.items():
            if key not in args:
                args[key] = value
        response = requests.get(
            Consts.URL['base'].format(
                proxy=self.region,
                region=self.region,
                url=api_url
                ),
            params=args
            )
        print response.url
        return response.json()
```

this is the only error i have received that i really don't know much on. Is this a result of there being no `.items` on my params? or i left it initialized as an empty dictionary?

EDIT 1: Have tried tinkering with the Tuple and items thing but just not having any luck, my error message is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cambria/Desktop/api/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cambria/Desktop/api/Main.py", line 5, in main
    respons3 = api.get_summoner_by_name('hi im gosan')
  File "/home/cambria/Desktop/api/RiotAPI.py", line 33, in get_summoner_by_name
    return self._request(api_url)
  File "/home/cambria/Desktop/api/RiotAPI.py", line 23, in _request
    params=args
  File "/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
>>>
```

as far as i can tell and have searched, this is a result of the python REQUESTS not going through completely?
and my new code as follows,

```
  def _request(self, api_url, params=None): #edit
        if params is None:                  #edit
            params = {}                     #edit
        args = {'api_key': self.api_key}
        for key, value in params.items(): #remove?? since there is no .items()?
            if key not in args:
                args[key] = value
        response = requests.get(
            Consts.URL['base'].format(
                proxy=self.region,
                region=self.region,
                url=api_url
                ),
            params=args
            )
        print response.url
        return response.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code expects `params` to be a dict `{}` (or have a `.items` method).  You've passed a tuple `()`.  The two are not equivalent.

Set `params` to `None` by default, and pass a when needed.

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=None):
    params = params if params is not None else {}
    ...
```

Or expect a list of tuples, rather than a dict.

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=()):
    for key, value in params:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A tuple `()` doesn't have a method named `items`. You probably mistake that for dictionary. Change you code as follows:

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=None):
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, posted this late last night. I have tried tinkering with your answer but i'm having no luck and am getting a giant error message that i will post in my OP edit 1

Comment: would you eliminate .items() since there is no method? but when i do, i just get this request error that i listed in the OP